# S3 Bucket Policy Restricting Access to Single Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket that is being accessed by multiple Lambdas. I want to restrict access to a single folder so that only a single Lambda can access it.

I have the following Cloud Formation template creating all the resources but I can't get the bucket policy condition right. It restricts access to the folder but doesn't grant access to my Lambda when my Lambda execution role is specified as an exception. Why doesn't template below work?

```
  ExampleBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::AccountId}-example-bucket'

  ExampleBucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref ExampleBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 's3:*'
            Effect: Deny
            Resource:
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ExampleBucket}/example-folder/
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ExampleBucket}/example-folder/*
            Principal: '*'
            Condition:
              ArnNotEquals:
                aws:SourceArn:
                  - !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-handler
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs12.x

  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role    
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action:
                - s3:GetObject
                - s3:ListBucket
                - s3:PutObject
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: 
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ExampleBucket}
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ExampleBucket}/*
              - Action: 
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
```

I get the following error : "StoreDB Error in function: putStoreObject, accessing key: example-folder/example-file, AWS S3 message: Access Denied"

Comment: Try `aws:PrincipalArn`

Comment: `aws:SourceArn` is your lambda's arn, not its role.

Comment: Thanks both. @jellycsc suggestion fixed it. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark as the solution.

Comment: @newprogrammer I'm glad it works. Please consider accepting my answer below if you find it helpful ◡̈

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP's comment, changing from `aws:SourceArn` to `aws:PrincipalArn` worked.